# angular2 get elementRef of component that is not a child

Tags: angular, elementref

In my app I have following structure:

```
<fin-header></fin-header>
<main></main>
<fin-footer></fin-footer>
```

In header I want to add scrolling to specific component of `main`. My scrolling method takes as argument `elementRef`. But I can't get one by `@ViewChild` 'cause components of `main` are not children of header.

Is there any chance to get `elementRef` of component that is not child?

Comment: I would think you could use the parent element to pass the elementRef of main to header. Can you add an output property in main that is an elementRef, and an input property in header of the same type, then, in the parent, set one to be the other in AfterViewInit?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could modify your structure a little and embed your components in a parent.
Something like:

```
<parent>
  <fin-header [elementRef]="mainRef"></fin-header>
  <main></main>
  <fin-footer></fin-footer>
<parent>
```

That way the parent could pass the reference of its child (main) to its other child (header).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `main` elementRef and use `nativeElement.parentElement` to get the parent and do another query on the DOM from the parent.
for example, if the structure is something like:

```
<div>
  <fin-header></fin-header>
  <main></main>
  <fin-footer></fin-footer>
</div>
```

Obtaining the `main`'s `elementRef` `nativeElement.parentElement` would be the div.
and of course, `div.querySelectorAll` would have all the div's children.